# Unable to fetch data in form from different tables in Access Form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access-2016

I am trying to fetch some data in a combobox from table2 in form1, the record source for the form1 is table1.

table1 - GetInputtbl
form1  - GetInputfrm
table2 - InputSheeter1

I am interested in the values in column Pallet1 in table InputSheeter1

I am able to do that but by using the the row source of the combobox as the following code only

```
SELECT [InputSHEETER1].[JOB], [InputSHEETER1].[Pallet1] FROM InputSHEETER1 ORDER 
BY [Pallet1];
```

When I try to use the query below, it doesn't work:

```
SELECT InputSHEETER1.[Pallet1] FROM InputSHEETER1;
```

Comment: Are you getting any error codes? Are you getting ANY results?  Is your combo-box multi-column or single column?

Comment: My combo-box is single column. When I am using the query : "SELECT InputSHEETER1.[Pallet1] FROM InputSHEETER1;" my dropdown in empty.

Comment: does it have something to do with Primary key column? Job is primary key column in InputSheeter1

Comment: Check your RowSourceType property is set to Table/Query

Comment: As it fails when selecting only one field, I guess your box is dual column, but first column-width is set to 0 and you see only second column. By selecting only one column, second one is empty and first ine not visible. Can you select an empty entry?

Comment: it is set to Table/Query

Comment: @ComputerVersteher You are right, changed it to 1 and it worked.

Comment: Yes count to 1 and set column-width > 0 of first column. If ComboBox is bound you may have to change bound column. Read [Add a list box or combo box](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-list-box-or-combo-box-70abf4a9-0439-4885-9099-b9fa83517603) to see most settings.